# How to make Jetpack Compose Image animating infinite

Tags: animation, android-jetpack-compose

I have an `animated-vector` drawable.
I want this animated vector to be animated in loop while this image is showing.
Cannot find a good solution for this.

```kotlin
        val image = animatedVectorResource(R.drawable.no_devices_animated)
        var atEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        Image(
            painter = image.painterFor(atEnd),
            "image",
            Modifier.width(150.dp).clickable {
                atEnd = !atEnd
            },
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit)
```

When I tap on the image it is animating but then stops. This is kind of an infinite progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leaving my solution here (using compose 1.2.0-alpha07).

Add the dependencies in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation-graphics:$compose_version"
}
```

And do the following:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalAnimationGraphicsApi
@Composable
fun AnimatedVectorDrawableAnim() {
    val image = AnimatedImageVector.animatedVectorResource(R.drawable.avd_anim)
    var atEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    // This state is necessary to control start/stop animation
    var isRunning by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    // The coroutine scope is necessary to launch the coroutine 
    // in response to the click event
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    // This function is called when the component is first launched
    // and lately when the button is pressed
    suspend fun runAnimation() {
        while (isRunning) {
            delay(1000) // set here your delay between animations
            atEnd = !atEnd
        }
    }
    // This is necessary just if you want to run the animation when the
    // component is displayed. Otherwise, you can remove it.
    LaunchedEffect(image) {
        runAnimation()
    }
    Image(
        painter = rememberAnimatedVectorPainter(image, atEnd),
        null,
        Modifier
            .size(150.dp)
            .clickable {
                isRunning = !isRunning // start/stop animation
                if (isRunning) // run the animation if isRunning is true.
                    scope.launch {
                        runAnimation()
                    }
            },
        contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(Color.Red)
    )
}
```

Case you need to repeat the animation from the start, the only way I find was create two vector drawables like `ic_start` and `ic_end` using the information declared in the animated vector drawable and do the following:

```kotlin
// this is the vector resource of the start point of the animation
val painter = rememberVectorPainter(
    image = ImageVector.vectorResource(R.drawable.ic_start)
)
val animatedPainter = rememberAnimatedVectorPainter(
    animatedImageVector = AnimatedImageVector.animatedVectorResource(R.drawable.avd_anim),
    atEnd = !atEnd
)

Image(
    painter = if (atEnd) painter else animatedPainter,
    ...
)
```

So, when the animated vector is at the end position, the static image is drawn. After the delay, the animation is played again. If you need a continuous repetition, set the delay as the same duration of the animation.

Here's the result:
[image]

Comment: `animatedVectorResource` is missing in Compose RC01 :(

Comment: Yeah, you right, but it will be back on next releases
https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1753821

Comment: Hey @nglauber thanks for this! I'm curious though - for some reason my animation plays forwards, then reverse, then forwards, and repeats. Why does it reverse and how can I stop that? I want to to play forward, then start over after the duration expires.

Comment: @DiscDev I edited the answer in order to try to help you ;)

Comment: @nglauber you are my hero =). Thank you, it works great. Hopefully they make this a little easier in the future. I just made the switch to Compose a week ago and it's the best thing since Kotlin was introduced.

Comment: None of these solutions covered my use case to have infinite repeatable AVD, so I ended up with AndroidView with ImageView and AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/resources#animated-vector-drawables

```
val image = AnimatedImageVector.animatedVectorResource(R.drawable.animated_vector)
val atEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Icon(
    painter = rememberAnimatedVectorPainter(image, atEnd),
    contentDescription = null
)
```

To make the animation loop infinitely:

```
val image = AnimatedImageVector.animatedVectorResource(id = vectorResId)
var atEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Image(
    painter = rememberAnimatedVectorPainter(animatedImageVector = image, atEnd = atEnd),
    contentDescription = null,
)
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    while (true) {
        delay(animDuration)
        atEnd = !atEnd
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Infinite loop without static images solution:**

Best working with animated vector drawable that is a loop.

First add the dependencies in your build.gradle

```gradle
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation-graphics:$compose_version"
}
```

**Animated loop loader**

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationGraphicsApi::class)
@Composable
fun Loader() {
    val image = AnimatedImageVector.animatedVectorResource(id = R.drawable.loader_cycle)
    var atEnd by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val painterFirst = rememberAnimatedVectorPainter(animatedImageVector = image, atEnd = atEnd)
    val painterSecond = rememberAnimatedVectorPainter(animatedImageVector = image, atEnd = !atEnd)

    val isRunning by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    suspend fun runAnimation() {
        while (isRunning) {
            atEnd = !atEnd
            delay(image.totalDuration.toLong())
        }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(image) {
        runAnimation()
    }
    Image(
        painter = if (atEnd) painterFirst else painterSecond,
        contentDescription = null,
    )
}
```

Right now I don't see any option to restart painter to start all over again - you need to rewind it. So in this solution we create two of those painter. One of them is starting with `!atEnd`. Each time `atEnd` is changed both of them do their work but **we display only one animating from start to end**. The other one is silently rewinding the animation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement a loading spinner using this approach, but encountered some issues.

I had an issue with the proposed solution, where the animation reverses back to the beginning. To prevent this, as @nglauber suggested, I tried switching to a static vector when the animation ends. Unfortunately, that wasn't smooth as the animation would have to wait for the delay before restarting.

This was the workaround that I used.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationGraphicsApi::class)
@Composable
fun rememberAnimatedVectorPainterCompat(image: AnimatedImageVector, atEnd: Boolean): Painter {
    val animatedPainter = rememberAnimatedVectorPainter(image, atEnd)
    val animatedPainter2 = rememberAnimatedVectorPainter(image, !atEnd)
    return if (atEnd) {
        animatedPainter
    } else {
        animatedPainter2
    }
}
```